# MySQL join 3 tables and having clause with SUM on activityScore column

Tags: mysql, join, sum, having

I have 3 tables : accounts, contacts, contact_activity. Accounts can have multiple contacts, also multiple activities whereas contacts can also have multiple activities. adding tables queries below:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `companyName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_duplicate` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `cmpCodes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'no',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `companyName`, `is_duplicate`, `cmpCodes`, `is_deleted`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1024, 'Vodafone Germany','no', 'imli02-0323', 'no', '2023-10-20 09:36:02', '2021-11-18 15:35:39'),
(1336, 'Microsoft', 'no', 'imli02-0323', 'no', '2023-11-23 20:02:03', '2021-12-20 14:16:29'),
(1234, 'Microsoft test','no', 'imli02-0323', 'no', '2023-11-23 20:02:03', '2021-12-20 14:16:29');


CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `accountId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmpMultiple` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_duplicate` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `is_deleted` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT 'no',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`, `accountId`, `name`, `cmpMultiple`, `is_duplicate`, `is_deleted`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
( 4543, 1336, 'alex', 'imli02-0323', 'no', 'no', '2023-08-15 15:13:22', '2023-11-20 10:24:44'),
( 4545, 1024, 'julie', 'imli02-0323', 'no', 'no', '2023-08-16 10:26:22', '2024-01-08 08:33:23'),
( 4742, 1336, 'Matt', 'imli02-0323', 'no', 'no', '2023-11-14 11:23:21', '2023-11-23 20:02:03'),
( 4744, 1336, 'Martin', 'imli02-0323', 'no', 'no', '2023-11-14 11:23:21', '2023-11-15 16:39:33'),
( 4743, 1336, 'Andrew', 'imli02-0323', 'no', 'no', '2023-11-14 11:23:22', '2023-11-23 19:02:48'),
( 3434, 1234, 'jack', 'imli02-0323', 'no', 'no', '2023-08-16 10:26:22', '2024-01-07 12:09:04');



CREATE TABLE `contact_activity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contactID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `accountId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'PD org id',
  `cmpCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activityScore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activityDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `contact_activity` (`id`, `contactID`, `accountId`, `cmpCode`, `activityScore`, `activityDate`, `created_at`) VALUES
(2442,  4543, 1336, 'imli02-0323', 3, '2023-08-15 16:13:35', '2023-08-15 17:13:36'),
(2451,  4545, 1024, 'imli02-0323', 8, '2023-08-16 11:27:24', '2023-08-16 12:27:25'),
(2695, 4543, 1336, 'imli02-0323', 3, '2023-10-09 16:24:50', '2023-10-09 17:24:51'),
(3116, 0, 1024, 'imli02-0323', 4, '2023-12-27 12:55:47', '2023-12-29 13:47:53');
```

I have written the following query to get the required output but it's not working:

```
SELECT `accounts`.`companyName` AS `name`,
      `accounts`.`id` AS `accountId`,
    SUM(contact_activity.activityScore) AS totalActivityScore,
    contact_activity.id AS activityid
    FROM
        `accounts`
    LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON `accounts`.`id` = `contacts`.`accountId` AND(
    `contacts`.`cmpMultiple` = 'imli02-0323' AND( `accounts`.`cmpCodes` = 'imli02-0323' OR accounts.cmpCodes = '' OR accounts.cmpCodes IS NULL
            )
        ) AND `contacts`.`is_duplicate` = 'no' AND `contacts`.`is_deleted` = 'no'
    INNER JOIN `contact_activity` ON
        (
            `contact_activity`.`contactID` = `contacts`.`id` AND `contact_activity`.`cmpCode` = 'imli02-0323' AND `contact_activity`.`contactID` IS NOT NULL
        ) OR(
            contact_activity.accountId = accounts.id AND contact_activity.cmpCode = 'imli02-0323' AND `contact_activity`.`accountId` IS NOT NULL
        )
    WHERE
        `accounts`.`is_duplicate` = 'no' AND `accounts`.`is_deleted` = 'no'  AND `contact_activity`.`activityScore` != ''
    GROUP BY
        `contact_activity`.`accountId`,
        `accounts`.`id`
    HAVING
        SUM(contact_activity.activityScore) >= 6;
```

the above query showing this result:

```
name             | accountId | totalActivityScore | activityid  
Vodafone Germany | 1024      | 12                 | 2451
Microsoft        | 1336      | 24                 | 2442
```

which is incorrect as for accountId 1336 we have only 2 entries in contact_activity and there sum is 6 but it's showing 24.

I need the following output :

```
name             | accountId | totalActivityScore | activityid  
Vodafone Germany | 1024      | 12                 | 2451
Microsoft        | 1336      | 6                  | 2442
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and format your code.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any justification for using find_in_set?

Comment: @P.Salmon cmpcode holds comma separated values that's why I have used find_in_set. but to make it easy I have kept one value in cmpcode.

Comment: sample data should be REPRESENTATIVE..

Comment: @P.Salmon I have updated the query and removed find_in_set

Comment: I disagree with your desired outcome 1024/julia is deleted so should be ignored when acquiring activity and activity_id is meaningless in the outcome..btw you don't seem to know when duplicate is set to yes.

Comment: you are selecting contact_activity.id but grouping by contact_activity.accountId; this results in an error if you use modern settings for mysql, and returns an arbitrary id from the contact_activity rows for the accountId.  do you need to select that?  if so, how do you want to determine which id to return?

Comment: since this is a very different question when cmpcode has multiple values, I recommend you leave those and the find_in_set in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is with the last OR which I think is intended to capture activity by company where no contact is involved BUT you aren't testing for that so 10 rows are aggregated when only 4 should be.

change to

```
 OR  
          (contact_activity.accountId = accounts.id AND 
           contact_activity.cmpCode = 'imli02-0323' AND `contact_activity`.`accountId` IS NOT NULL and
          contactid= 0
        )
```

Note the query will fail if only_full_group_by is set

https://dbfiddle.uk/PG8OclY6

Answer (score 0):

Please use mysql function to calculate total activity score of account.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `f_getTotalActivityScoreOfAccount`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `f_getTotalActivityScoreOfAccount`(_id INT 
    ) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _total INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT SUM(activityScore) FROM contact_activity WHERE accountId = _id AND contactID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE accountId = _id AND is_deleted = 'yes') INTO _total;
    RETURN _total;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

```
SELECT `accounts`.`companyName` AS `name`,
      `accounts`.`id` AS `accountId`,
    f_getTotalActivityScoreOfAccount(`accounts`.`id`) AS totalActivityScore,
    contact_activity.id AS activityid
    FROM
        `accounts`
    LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON `accounts`.`id` = `contacts`.`accountId` AND(
            FIND_IN_SET(
                'imli02-0323',
                contacts.cmpMultiple
            ) AND(
                FIND_IN_SET(
                    'imli02-0323',
                    accounts.cmpCodes
                ) OR accounts.cmpCodes = '' OR accounts.cmpCodes IS NULL
            )
        ) AND `contacts`.`is_duplicate` = 'no' AND `contacts`.`is_deleted` = 'no'
    INNER JOIN `contact_activity` ON
        (
            `contact_activity`.`contactID` = `contacts`.`id` AND `contact_activity`.`cmpCode` = 'imli02-0323' AND `contact_activity`.`contactID` IS NOT NULL
        ) OR(
            contact_activity.accountId = accounts.id AND contact_activity.cmpCode = 'imli02-0323' AND `contact_activity`.`accountId` IS NOT NULL
        )
    WHERE
        `accounts`.`is_duplicate` = 'no' AND `accounts`.`is_deleted` = 'no'  AND `contact_activity`.`activityScore` != ''
    GROUP BY
        `contact_activity`.`accountId`,
        `accounts`.`id`
    HAVING
        SUM(contact_activity.activityScore) >= 6;
```

Comment: for accountId 1024 there 2 entries in contact_activity table where one entry solely belongs to account and second belongs to contact which belongs to account 1024 and let's assume the contact of that activity is set to deleted then it should not count the score of that activity.

Comment: then you can change function code.
I'll update my answer.

Comment: according to function the activity score output is shown correct but if we change the having clause value to 12 then only one account should be shown in output that is 1024 as for account id 1336 the sum of activities is only 6